# Entity Framework Invalid column name Height_HeightID

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, sqlclient

I am trying to get records from the Height Table based on foreign key relationships with parent table. But I am getting Invalid Column Name.... Error. Here is my model setup:-

```
[Table("Candidate")]
public partial class Candidate
{
    public Candidate()
    {
        Heights = new HashSet<Height>();
        Weights = new HashSet<Weight>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int CandidateID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a Height and Weight Table. Model of Height table is:-

```
[Table("Height")]    
public partial class Height
    {
        [Key]
        public int HeightID { get; set; }
        public int? CandidateID { get; set; }
        public double? HeightVal { get; set; }
        ForeignKey("CandidateID")]
        public virtual Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is LinQ query:-

```
return (from c in _db.Candidates
        join h in _db.Heights
            on c.CandidateID equals h.CandidateID
        where c.CandidateID == candidateId
        select t);
```

When i try to get records using these models, I am getting this error:-

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name
>   'Height_HeightID

As suggested by similar stackoverflow, I have added ForeignKey[] DataAnnotation but I am still getting same error.

Also in my Sql Server Database, Height Table has foreign key constraint on CandidateID.

Comment: This code looks like it should work with no problems. Is anything being configured in the fluent API in your `OnModelCreating`? Or have you left any properties out in your example?

Comment: OnModelCreating. which is created automatically has no mention about Height And Candidate foreignkey relationship.

Comment: Sounds like you have a Height property in you Candidate class.

Comment: @tschmit007: yes. Height property is in Candidate Class + virtual ICollection<Height> Heights property too.

Comment: tschmit007. Please give me a clue. What I suppose to do with Height Property?

Comment: Could you post a complete example? Your example shows `Candidate` without a `Height` property.